# "program.exe doesn't exist" in VSCode when i try to use an external window

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

EDIT : the g++ is in my path, it isn't the problem.

I have been trying to use a `launch.json` to run my c++ programs in the external terminal, but every time it gives me an error `program.exe doesn't exist` although it works fine in the VS Code terminal.

[image]

Here is how the `launch.json` is configured:

```json
{
    "configurations": [
    {
        "name": "run and debug",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": true,
        "MIMode": "gdb",
        "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\gdb.exe",
        "setupCommands": [
            {
                "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            },
            {
                "description":  "Set Disassembly Flavor to Intel",
                "text": "-gdb-set disassembly-flavor intel",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            }
        ]
    }
    ]
}
```

Comment: You should avoid using spaces in your path as it can cause problems in building your application since a space on the command line splits separate arguments requiring quoting the path.

Comment: Look at the command run in the terminal.

Comment: i changed it to no spaces and it doesn't work still

Comment: Are you sure that the program have been built without errors? And in in the path mentioned by that dialog? And named like in the dialog?

Comment: If the program compiled successfully and the full path and filename are correct perhaps your antivirus deleted your executable.

Comment: it was indeed my antivirus thank you!